# Camel + sql + error handling

Tags: apache-camel

I have a task to handle all incoming messages within the route and save them to database. 
My route starts with webservice (camel-cxf), and then process to ejb and return soap response.

I've decided to use camel-sql component. As far as I don't have any problems with logging incoming message:

```
<camelContext id="InstitutionContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <onException>
        <exception>org.example.MyException</exception>
        <continued><constant>true</constant></continued>
        <to uri="bean:myExceptionHandler?method=handle" />
    </onException>

    <route id="InstitutionRoute" >
        <from uri="direct:start" />
        <to uri="sql:insert into translog(id,type,data) values(2,'IN',#)" />
        <split>
            <tokenize token="\n" />
            <unmarshal>
                <csv delimiter=";" />
            </unmarshal>
            <process ref="InstitutionProcessorTest" />
        </split>
        <to uri="bean:myExceptionHandler?method=checkErrors" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

but I don't have idea how to handle exceptions and save them in the form of SOAP message.

```
<onCompletion onFailureOnly="true">
    <to uri="sql:insert into translog(id,type,data) values(2,'ERROR',#)" />
</onCompletion>
```

but it saves original message in data column. Is there any body who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but it looks you are trying to save the SOAP message in XML format if there is a exception.

By default the dataFormat for CXF is POJO meaning it sends a POJO around the camel route i.e. the SOAP XML is converted to a POJO.

Two options come to mind:

1. Set the dataformat to message or payload. This will send the XML message across the camel route instead of a POJO
2. Marshall the POJO into a XML message and save it.